# Oracle SQL Query Tuning for output

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an output such as below

```
select City, Gender, count(*) from  tablename group by City, Gender ;

City      Gender   count(*)
Chennai   Male     640000
Chennai   Female   623000
Blore     Male     500000
Blore     Female   600000
Pune      Male     700000
Pune      Female   700000
```

But I am looking for getting the same output as like below

```
City          Male          Female
Chennai       640000        623000
Blore         500000        600000
Pune          700000        700000
```

Appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe try to use subquery? It may not be efficient with many Cities but for ad-hoc query will be OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need conditional `sum` for this

```
select
City,
sum(case when Gender = 'Male' then 1 else 0 end) as Male,
sum(case when Gender = 'Female' then 1 else 0 end) as Female
from  tablename group by City
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is short code

select city,sum(male),sum(female) from tablename group by city;